# Getting StreamCorruptedException in Android AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am implementing an AsyncTask to interact with a Servlet. I get a certificate and a challenge (ChallengeMessage), I answer this challenge and then i get a validation answer (String).

I don't know why I am getting a StreamCorrupted exception when I send the ChallengeMessage to the servlet (the only writeObject() i do in the code). Here is my doInBackground method.

I know this is not the best code you've seen, this is just some quick testing.

```
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

    try {           

        URL url = new URL("ValidURL");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.i("URL", "VERIFIER CREATED");

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        Log.i("STREAM", "STREAMS CREATED");            

        //Receive CA certificate + challenge
        ChallengeMessage challenge = (ChallengeMessage) in.readObject();
        certificateCA = challenge.getCertificate();
        byte[] nonce = challenge.getNonce();
        //Log.i("Nonce", nonce.toString());

        //Hash challenge and send back with user certificate
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hashedNonce = md.digest(nonce);
        //Log.i("Digest", hashedNonce.toString());

        ChallengeMessage challengeResponse = new ChallengeMessage(hashedNonce, (X509Certificate)params[1]);           
        out.writeObject(challengeResponse); //Here I get the StreamCorruptedException
        out.flush();            

        String mResp = (String) in.readObject();
        Log.i("ANSWER",mResp);            

        in.close();
        out.close();
        connection.disconnect();

        return mResp;

    } catch(ProtocolException e) {
        Log.i("VERIFIER", e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }

    return "False";
}
```

And this is the StackTrace

```
    08-22 12:43:23.764: W/System.err(30506): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
08-22 12:43:23.774: W/System.err(30506):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
08-22 12:43:23.774: W/System.err(30506):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
08-22 12:43:23.774: W/System.err(30506):    at cat.urv.tfg.tasks.VerifyCredentialsTask.doInBackground(VerifyCredentialsTask.java:76)
08-22 12:43:23.774: W/System.err(30506):    at cat.urv.tfg.tasks.VerifyCredentialsTask.doInBackground(VerifyCredentialsTask.java:1)
08-22 12:43:23.774: W/System.err(30506):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-22 12:43:23.774: W/System.err(30506):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-22 12:43:23.774: W/System.err(30506):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-22 12:43:23.774: W/System.err(30506):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-22 12:43:23.774: W/System.err(30506):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-22 12:43:23.784: W/System.err(30506):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Post the exact error message and the stack trace.

Comment: Very hard to believe. Sure it isn't thrown at readObject()?

Comment: Sure, I logged it and the results are the the expected ones. However, it "crashes" in the readObject() sentence.

Comment: I mean writeObject(), sorry

Comment: +1 for EJP's comment. Even if you get past `writeObject()`, you will get a `StreamCorruptedException` on `readObject()` because you do not call `out.close()` first.